# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after building jar in Intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

i am new to scala, sbt and Intellij and can't for my life get a working .jar file build. I am trying to build a Apache Kafka consumer application for AWS EMR which connects and processes messages from Kafka topics. For that reason I need a .jar file of my application which i can upload to the spark cluster.

I created an Intellij project and adjusted my build.sbt to look as follows:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

val sparkVersion = "3.1.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.12.15"
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "kafkaStreaming"
  )
```

Here is my application code:

```
package test.kafkaStreaming

import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object kafkaConsumer {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    if (args.length == 0) {
      println("dude, i need at least one parameter")
    }
    val Array(brokers, topics) = args
    val topicsSet: Array[String] = topics.split(",")

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("kafkaStreaming").setMaster("local[*]")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))

    val kafkaParams = Map(
      "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
      "bootstrap.servers" -> brokers,
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "spark-streaming-notes",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest"
    )

    val dstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams)
    )

    dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.take(10).foreach(println)
    }

    ssc.start
    ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = false)
  }
}
```

The application runs fine in the Intellij environment. I tried to build a JAR file using the following method in Intellij:

- File => Project Structure => Artifacts
- Add new Artifact => JAR => From modules with dependencies

Those are my settings:

[image]

After confirming those settings I have the option to add all those files here. I guess those are all the dependencies my application needs to run.

[image]

When i add those files, build a .jar, and execute the .jar, I get the following error message

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.kafkaStreaming.kafkaConsumer
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.RichClassLoader$.$anonfun$run$1(ScalaClassLoader.scala:95)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.RichClassLoader$.run$extension(ScalaClassLoader.scala:95)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:27)
        at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.run(MainGenericRunner.scala:21)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:36)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
        at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runAndCatch(MainGenericRunner.scala:21)
        at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runJar(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:79)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:92)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:108)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

When I don't add those files, I am able to run the .jar using

```
scala .\kafkaStreaming.jar
```

but all dependencies are missing and I have to manually add them via -cp.

My MANIFEST.MF looks like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: test.kafkaStreaming.kafkaConsumer
```

I hope you might be able to help me.

Comment: Gradle or Maven?

Comment: Not sure TBH, but since your module is `kafkaStreaming`, maybe you should pass kafkaStreaming.KafkaConsumer instead?

Comment: So, the IDE settings shouldn't be used. Nothing needs extracted either. You should have the same behavior as using `sbt` command directly to build. You will need to use the sbt-assembly module, though, and you must run the code using spark-submit